# How to hide a class using internal keyword?

Tags: c#, oop, class, abstract-class, internal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c# internal abstract class, how to hide usage outside assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244953/c-sharp-internal-abstract-class-how-to-hide-usage-outside-assembly)

I have a common assembly/project that has several abstract classes. When I create a new assembly, the developer should derive from `MathProblem` and `MathProblemTemplate<T>` classes.

So, I guess the class `MathProblemTemplate` can be `internal`, I mean when you plan to set a base class to a concrete class, not show in intellisense the class `MathProblemTemplate`, but yes for `MathProblemTemplate<T>`

```
// Question classes
public abstract class Question
{
    protected QuestionTemplate Template { get; private set; }

    public Question(QuestionTemplate template)
    {
        this.Template = template;
    }
}

public abstract class MathProblem : Question
{
    public MathProblem(MathProblemTemplate template)
        : base(template)
    {
    }
}

// QuestionTemplate classes
public abstract class QuestionTemplate
{
    public QuestionTemplate() { }
}

// This is the class which I'd like to hide
public abstract class MathProblemTemplate : QuestionTemplate
{
}

public abstract class MathProblemTemplate<T> : MathProblemTemplate
{
    protected abstract T Method1();
    protected abstract T Method2(); 
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read [this relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244953/c-sharp-internal-abstract-class-how-to-hide-usage-outside-assembly) that showed up in the list when you asked your question?

Comment: Yes, I've read it, but I'm still getting errors like: Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'DevNinja.Core.Models.MathProblemTemplate' is less accessible than class 'DevNinja.Core.Models.MathProblemTemplate<T>'

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you're using templates which makes it different.

Comment: Aside from the nasty friends hack, the answer to the question that @TomWijsman referred you to,says you can't do this. If you want to derive from the class in another assembly, it has to be public.

Comment: Well my intention is just to show the generic class and hide the non generic

Comment: What is the motivation for having the non generic version?

Comment: Because my MathProblem class needs in its constructor a concrete class for it, as I can't set a generic value, I set a non generic class

Comment: Hmm, you should be able to use any concrete class that works in the non generic version with the generic version?  If I'm missing something please update the question with a bit more detail in the code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'you should be able to use any concrete class that works in the non generic version with the generic version'?

Answer (score 3):

You can't, the reason is that `MathProblemTemplate<T>` is public, therefore any class it inherits from also needs to be public.

You could just remove `MathProblemTemplate` and move any code in it into `MathProblemTemplate<T>`

Comment: But I need a reference from it in MathProblem constructor, that's the reason why I really need the generic

Comment: In that case, you might have to make MathProblem generic and then supply the generic MathProblemTemplate e.g. `public abstract class MathProblem<T> : Question { public MathProblem(MathProblemTemplate<T> template) { } }`

Comment: But <T> would be redundant because this should be a MathProblemTemplate. Don't you think so?

Comment: What types do you use in the generic version?